# How to read this UAV Muffler Sound Test Charts?

Tags: acoustics

Just downloaded this UAV Muffler Sound Test Charts (PDF) file from [here](https://www.nwuav.com/products-uav-mufflers.html). e.g. here is an image of the table in the file:

[image: W]

I have several questions on it:

1. Why is there written a constant number next to Oct. band frequencies? e.g. for 50Hz you can just see 35.1 in all the row.
2. What do these colors mean? e.g. what does green color mean? Does it mean "you cannot hear the noise of the UAV"?
3. There is a scale labled "measurement Distance" and all the row is 2. What does this row mean?
4. Totally how do you read such a table?

Comment: Your point 3, the sensor is 2m from the source, but you need to check the detail as the * may have further meaning.

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you, I agree but there is nothing about * or any details in the file unfortunatly.

Comment: did you check the internet for general info regarding aural nondetectability? here's a document that defines the scope, and that includes several tables. https://novaintegration.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/MIL-STD-1474D.pdf

Comment: @GürkanÇetin Perfect! I think that's what I need.

Comment: @GürkanÇetin: Could you please write your answer as an answer?